# Looping through folder with SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, vba, excel

```
strQuery = _
     "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$A15:E999] " & _
     "IN '" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Source1.xlsx' " & _
     "[Excel 12.0;Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Mode=Read;ExtendedProperties='HDR=YES;'] " & _
     "UNION " & _
     "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$A15:E999] " & _
     "IN '" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Source2.xlsx' " & _
     "[Excel 12.0;Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Mode=Read;Extended Properties='HDR=YES;'] " & _
     "UNION " & _
     "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$A15:E999] " & _
     "IN '" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Source3.xlsx' " & _
     "[Excel 12.0;Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Mode=Read;Extended Properties='HDR=YES;'] " & _
     "ORDER BY A;"
```

Good morning,

I have one last nail to go on this coding I have and any help is much appreciated. I am gathering numerous files from a single folder and file names are different (although data order and data are same).

Question is:

- Is it possible to get all files via the 'strQuery' without slowing down the code? How do I go on to do this? (eg: I think maybe loop but it might slow down? - see below)
- Is it possible to get (say) 100 excel file data read at once? (although I do not know names of it?)

I can modify strQuery (via assigning it a text string) and input a loop to go through every file but I recon this would require me to create a connection for every single file rather than all at once?

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

--

Full Code below (I didn't know where to put this in a visible manner)

```
Sub SqlUnionTest()

Dim strConnection As String
Dim strQuery As String
Dim objConnection As Object
Dim objRecordSet As Object, qText As String

strConnection = _
    "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
    "User ID=Admin;" & _
    "Data Source='" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & "';" & _
    "Mode=Read;" & _
    "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Macro;"";"


Dim sFile As String

sFile = Dir(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\*.xlsx")

Do While sFile <> ""

    strQuery = _
     "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$A15:E999] " & _
     "IN '" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & sFile & _
     "[Excel 12.0;Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Mode=Read;ExtendedProperties='HDR=YES;'] " & _
     "UNION "

    sFile = Dir()

Loop

strQuery = Left(strQuery, Len(strQuery) - 7) 'to remove last UNION which is not necessary

Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
objConnection.Open strConnection
Set objRecordSet = objConnection.Execute(strQuery)
RecordSetToWorksheet Sheets(1), objRecordSet
objConnection.Close

End Sub

Sub RecordSetToWorksheet(objSheet As Worksheet, objRecordSet As Object)

Dim i As Long

With objSheet
    .Cells.Delete
    For i = 1 To objRecordSet.Fields.Count
        .Cells(1, i).Value = objRecordSet.Fields(i - 1).Name
    Next
    .Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset objRecordSet
    .Cells.Columns.AutoFit
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [DIR()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk008ty4(v=vs.90).aspx) function to loop through all the `.xlsx` files in the folder without knowing the specific file names. If you need to weed out any files, you can  place conditional testing inside the loop.

*Code untested*

```
Dim sFile As String, strQuery As String

sFile = Dir(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\*.xlsx")

Do While sFile <> ""

    strQuery = strQuery & _
     "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$A15:E999] " & _
     "IN '" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & sFile & _
     "[Excel 12.0;Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Mode=Read;ExtendedProperties='HDR=YES;'] " & _
     "UNION;"

    sFile = Dir()

Loop

strQuery = Left(strQuery, Len(strQuery) - 7) 'to remove last UNION which is not necessary
```

Comment: Hi,

Thanks and this is the idea I had but couldn't place it in coding!
Thanks again. Its give me an error 

Run-time error '-2122..
"filepath\source3.xlsx[excel 12.0;provider=Microsoft.ace.oledb....
is not a valid name. Make sure that it does not include invalid characters or punctuation and that it is not too long."

I am still trying to run it with 3 files which works using my code at original question. If I remove the 3rd file, it shows the error on 2nd file. The error appears on line 

`code`Set objRecordSet = objConnection.Execute(strQuery)

Appreciate your input!

Comment: I've put in what code (full code) I am using as of this point in my original question

Comment: @Dingo - do a `debug.print` on `strQuery` after it's built and look for where the syntax is off and adjust. In concept my code will work, but you'll need to do the debugging to figure out the kinks

Comment: Scott, thank you!
I've added the following as well as a apostrophe and it worked! 
strQuery = strQuery & _

Comment: @dingo - Ah, yes. Sorry about that. I edited my answer for same.